# Share image from resources

Tags: android

How can I share an image from the drawable folder with ShareActionProvider?
I have proved a lot of things but it doesn´t work.

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

What is the uri in this case? Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.example/" + R.drawable.photo); does not work.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with 'does not work'? What is the result?     Is `com.android.example` really your package name?

Comment: If I share with gmail I don´t receive the image, if I share with facebook I get a message "it can´t be added one or more elements", ...

Answer (score 3):

You can't get path of the **drawable** like this as the **resource** folder is compiled into the apk, but you can grab the resource like this:

```
Resources res= getResources();
Drawable drawable= res.getDrawable(R.drawable.photo);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, drawable, opts);
```

Then write this in memory then can get the **uri** of that **resource**.